# RStudio not exporting while TeXworks does

Tags: pdftex, rstudio, cancel

### Problem Overview

I want to use the `cancel`-package for my R-Markdown-file `project.rmd`. For that, I created a `preamble.tex`-file with following content:

```tex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
```

I included it in the YAML-Header of the RMD-file:

```yml
output:
  pdf_document:
    include:
      include_header: "preamble.tex"
```

The code I want to use is the following:

```latex
\[x+\cancel{5y}=0\]
```

However, when I want to export the file to PDF, I get following error-message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.363 x+\cancel
               {5y}=0
```

When looking at the created `project.tex`-file from my document, I found out that the line `\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}` wasn't included in said `project.tex`-file:

```latex
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
...
```

Why isn't the whole content of `preamble.tex` carried over to the exporting process?

### Attempts at fixing

I first created a new file `test.tex` with following content:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
x+\cancel{5y}=0 
\]

\end{document}
```

I opened it in TeXworks and tried to export it to PDF. It told me that I have a missing package called `cancel.sty`, which apparently wasn't installed already. After installing it, my file could be exported to PDF without a problem (Credits to @DavidCharlisle).

When adding the line `\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}` to the preamble of `project.tex`, the export to PDF in TeXworks also worked without fail. However, when I want to export `project.rmd` to pdf, I still get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.364 \[x+\cancel
                 {5y}=0\]
```

Also, when I want to export `project.tex` (the version which worked in TeXworks) in RStudio, I still get an error.

Why does Texworks function properly while RStudio does not?

### Context

I am using Windows 10 with MikTex. I have updated MikTex and all the packages in RStudio.

Comment: `\require` is not a latex command (you are probably using mathjax) for latex you want `\usepackage{cancel}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\require` worked for the preview in RStudio; without it, `\cancel` wouldn't have worked in said preview. As for your suggestion: I already implemented the line `\usepackage{cancel}` in the `preamble.tex` file, which is inculded in the YAML-Header of my RMD-File. Unfortunately, it did nothing to solve my problem.

Comment: `\require` is mathjax equivalent of latex `\usepackage`  you need `\require` (or a javascript load) for mathjax and `\usepackage` for latex, you aso need to remove the blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as it turns out I am very stupid:

instead of

```yml
output:
  pdf_document:
    include:
      include_header: "preamble.tex"
```

I should have written

```yml
output:
  pdf_document:
    include:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
```

I wrote `include_header:` instead of `in_header:`, thus the preamble was't able to load properly. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

`\require` is not a latex command, it is the mathjax equivalent of `\usepackage` so you should arrange exporting your markdown just uses one or the other. For pdf via latex you should generate

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
x+\cancel{5y}=0 
\]

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I just copied your code into a new file in my working directory and tried to export it to pdf, but I just got an error message

Comment: @Taxifahrer I show here a complete error free latex file that makes the pdf shown. If you are starting with markdown or some other system that exports to latex you need to check that the generated latex looks like this. Presumably a markdown file would _only_ have `\[ x+\cancel{5y}=0  \]` the latex preamble would be added on export

Comment: I have opened my new tex-file with your code in TeXworks and and tried to export it there. It told me that I have a missing file named cancel.sty, it appears that it wasn't installed for whatever reason (despite MikTex telling me the cancel-package is installed). After installing the file, I could export your code to PDF in TeXworks. I still have a problem though, and I will have to rephrase my question because of that.